# Как реализовать авторизацию по токену в SPECTACULAR_UI?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, authenticationtoken

Возникла проблема с авторизацией в моём SPECTACULAR. Для стандартной авторизации я использую knox.

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'api.errors_handler.errors_responses.custom_exception_handler',
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',),

    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FileUploadParser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}

REST_KNOX = {
    'USER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.users.CreateUserSerializer',
    'TOKEN_TTL': timedelta(hours=48)
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL='users.User'
```

Авторизация работает, токены успешно создаются и проверяются, но не в моём SPECTACULAR_UI. Я попытался импортировать knox авторизацию в настройки SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS, но кнопка авторизации просто пропала. Тогда я попытался проделать авторизацию с помощью:

```py
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'TITLE': 'Wallet',
    'DESCRIPTION': 'Wallet',
    'VERSION': '1.0.0',
    'SERVE_PERMISSIONS': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
    'SERVE_AUTHENTICATION': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'SWAGGER_SETTINGS': {
        'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
        'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
            'Token': {
                'type': 'apiKey',
                'name': 'Authorization',
                'in': 'header'
            }
        },
        'SECURITY': [{'Token': []}],
        'deepLinking': True,
        "displayOperationId": True,
        "syntaxHighlight.active": True,
        "syntaxHighlight.theme": "arta",
        "defaultModelsExpandDepth": -1,
        "displayRequestDuration": True,
        "filter": True,
        "requestSnippetsEnabled": True,
    },
    'COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST': True,
    'SORT_OPERATIONS': False,
    'ENABLE_DJANGO_DEPLOY_CHECK': False,
    'DISABLE_ERRORS_AND_WARNINGS': True,
}
```

Но это тоже не помогло, кнопка авторизации появилась, но токен так и не добавился в заголовки, что я не так делаю? Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо.